# Looking for pdf viewer/editor which stores sessions so it can be open in windows version

Tags: dual-boot, pdf

I use dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu, and I often change OS on daily basis.
My research depends strongly on lots of opened pdf-s in same time.
When I am in middle of work on, for example, Ubuntu, often I have to log in to windows and have to continue my research, but problem is that I have to search  and open all that pdf-s one by one.

So I am looking for solution which allows some kind of login so both software versions (Ubuntu and windows) after login bring me recent state from the other, so that research could be continued smoothly.

I tried Mendeley (and I keep using it) but their pdf-reader lacks some features I demand (go to previous view for example).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @K7AAY but virtualisation is not solution because I run a few high memory consuming programs. (Ubuntu 18.04)